# how convert datetime to timestamp on cqlsh

Tags: datetime, cassandra, timestamp, cql, cqlsh

I'm new in cassandra and specially to the cql syntax. But I have a created a column that is timestamp which gets me datetime as this '2018-05-18 03:08:58.246000+0000' but where I filter by created I get this error

```
InvalidRequest: Error froim server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unable to coerce '2018-05-18 03:08:58.246000+0000' to formatted date (long)"
```

Which lead me to think that I either need to convert the datetime into a tick or do some sort of casting.

how convert datetime to timestamp on cqlsh in a where clause?

Comment: Can you edit your post to contain your query?

Answer (score 4):

Although Cassandra stores timestamp fractions using the **.ffffff** format defined by the ISO 8601 standard as you mentioned.

```
cqlsh:test_keyspace> select * from timestamp_table ;

timestamp                       | other_field
---------------------------------+---------------
2018-05-18 03:08:58.246000+0000 | Other content
2018-05-18 03:08:58.000000+0000 | Other content
```

When interacting with the database (ie. INSERT, SELECT, ...) you need to use the ***.fff*** format like so:

```
cqlsh:test_keyspace> select * from timestamp_table WHERE timestamp='2018-05-18 03:08:58.123+0000';

timestamp                       | other_field
---------------------------------+---------------
2018-05-18 03:08:58.123000+0000 | Other content
```

Otherwise you will get the error you mentioned.

**Error when Reading**

```
 cqlsh:test_keyspace> select * from timestamp_table WHERE timestamp='2018-05-18 03:08:58.123000+0000';
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unable to coerce '2018-05-18 03:08:58.123000+0000' to a formatted date (long)"
```

**Error when writing**

```
cqlsh:test_keyspace> INSERT INTO timestamp_table (timestamp , other_field ) VALUES ( '2018-05-18 03:08:58.123456+0000', 'Other content');
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unable to coerce '2018-05-18 03:08:58.123456+0000' to a formatted date (long)"
```